# How to handle incomplete transaction with stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, stripe-payments

So I've created a checkout session with stripe, and provided a cancel_url as per the documentation, but the problem is that the cancel_url only gets navigated to when the user presses the back button as provided by stripe. What I would like to do is send an email to the user if the stripe transaction is not completed. So I would like to cover the cases where the user uses the stripe back button, browser back button, closes the tab or window, or navigates away from the page. Here are the relevant snippets of my javascript code

### Frontend.  (Angular)

```
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
fetch(`${environment.apiURL}/${endpoint}`, {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'

   },
   body: JSON.stringify(this.myForm.value)
 })
 .then(function(response) {
   return response.json();
 })
 .then(async function(session) {
   const stripe = await loadStripe(stripe_publish_key);
   return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
 })
 .then(function(result) {
   // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
   // error, you should display the localized error message to your
   // customer using `error.message`.
   if (result.error) {
     alert(result.error.message);
   }
 });
```

And then my server side code using express.js

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(secret);
...
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    customer_email: email,
    line_items: [
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: 'usd',
          product_data: {
            name: 'xxx',
          },
          unit_amount: xxx,
          product_data: {
            name: "xxx",
            description: `xxx`
        },
        },
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `${baseUrl}/success?email=${email}&name=${fullName}&type=pay-in-full`,
    cancel_url: `${baseUrl}/apply-now?email=${email}&name=${fullName}&cancel=true`,
  });

  res.send({id:session.id});
```

And the stripe packages I'm using

```
 "@stripe/stripe-js": "^2.1.0",
 "stripe": "^13.1.0",
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe doesn't handle anything other than the `cancel_url` and `success_url`.
-The `cancel_url` is the link the customer will be redirected to if they press the 'back' button on the Session.
-The `success_url` is the link the customer will be redirected to if they successfully complete the Session (=>charge succeeded or pending).

What Stripe does have is a recovery feature, which might help here:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/abandoned-carts

By enabling `recovery` in your Checkout Session, Stripe will generate a non-perishable link to that Session if the Session expires*.
You can listen for `checkout.session.expired` events with a webhook endpoint, then send this link to your customer (you're using `customer_email`, so you must be collecting the email prior to creating the Session).

*Session expire after 24h. You cannot increase this threshold, but you can reduce it, down to 30mn, using `expires_at`:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/abandoned-carts#adjust-session-expiration
(You can also use the expire() method on the Sessions API).

To loop back to your issue:

> I would like to cover the cases where the user uses the stripe back button, browser back button, closes the tab or window, or navigates away from the page.

-back button = `cancel_url`
-browser back button = the customer should get redirected back to your endpoint, you could implement it to handle a second visit after Session creation differently.
-closes window = use `recovery` and emails.